# can you still use windows 8 and have ubuntu as the desktop?

Tags: 12.10

I have watched tons of videos on this topic and i have looked it up all over the internet and it does seem to help. i want to know that i can still use windows 8 programs and features while having 12.10 as my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

i did not get actually what you want. but if you want to use windows programs you can use wine and about windows 8 in your ubuntu box you can prefer for VMWare...